# Как заставить udp терять пакеты в локальной сети?

Tags: сеть, winsock

Какие действия нужно совершить в **программе** чтобы, допустим, было пропущено сообщение. Пробовал ставить sleep перед приемом, все равно доходит)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они доходят, потому что **диспетчер ввода-вывода** пишет их в буфер вашего приложения, независимо от того что она сейчас делает.

Если вы хотите создать плохие условия прохождения пакетов, то подобная реализация называется "моделирование неработающей или плохо работающей сети" (simulation broken network), реализуется с помощью специальных программ, которые позволяют делать это в несколько кликов.

Одна из подобных программ [clumsy](https://jagt.github.io/clumsy/), можете по своим условиям моделировать любые проблемы в сети (Эмуляция пропадающих пакетов, дублирование пакетов, задержка пакетов, изменение порядка и т.д.)

Comment: а буфер приложения программно урезать нельзя?

Comment: @Kopkan Я думаю, можно уменьшить размер буфера сетевого адаптера и тогда пакеты которые не успевают обработаться, будут просто отброшены. Это нужно зайти в диспетчер устройств - сетевые адаптеры - название адаптара - дополнительно - Receive Buffers или Буферы приема.

Comment: Хотя можно и без программного метода, разрезать сетевой кабель, снять экранирование, и проложить его вдоль электропроводки, или люминесцентную лампу обмотать им и включать ее, когда нужны помехи, но через программу удобнее :)